# JobIntentService for devices having versions Oreo and above

Tags: android, background-process, android-10.0, jobintentservice

I have used JobIntentService to download the data in background and storing the data into the ormlite database. While using JobIntentService the device dozes off then it gets stuck and don't download the data further in Android Q. Also if it runs properly then I am not able to access the db data which is being downloaded in onHandleIntent(). It shows null object reference. I want to download the data irrespective of whether it is in dozed mode or not and also I want to access the db data properly. Does anybody have the solution for this?

Comment: "I want to download the data irrespective of whether it is in dozed mode" -- that has nothing to do with `JobIntentService`. It has everything to do with how and when you are trying to start it. In general, you do not have the ability to do work at arbitrary times in the background, and you may or may not have Internet access at that time. `WorkManager` would let you specify that you want Internet access when your work is to be done. See https://developer.android.com/guide/background for more on background work in Android.

Comment: @CommonsWare It has internet access all the time. Also I tried using workmanager but I want to pass data into the service through intent and in workmanager I am not able to pass the data with custom data types such as an object or an enum.

Comment: "It has internet access all the time" -- then you might want to expand your question with a [mcve] and a more detailed explanation of what "I am not able to access the db data which is being downloaded" means. "in workmanager I am not able to pass the data with custom data types such as an object or an enum" -- your code that is starting the `JobIntentService` is getting that data from somewhere. Perhaps your `Worker` can get the data from that same place.

Comment: @CommonsWare I am sending thr data through intent in JobIntentService but WorkManager has Data as data type and it doesn't support the datatypes other than the primitive ones that is why I am not able to paas the data there.

Comment: "I am sending thr data through intent in JobIntentService" -- correct. And there is some code that is calling `enqueueWork()` to do that. The code that is calling `enqueueWork()` is getting the data from somewhere to put into the `Intent` (database, `SharedPreferences`, some other type of file, etc.). Your `Worker` can get the data from that same "somewhere".

Comment: @CommonsWare that is what I am saying worker is not accepting that data. I have tried this then only I have raised a question over here. Can you tell me the syntax in which I can send an enum object to the worker?

Comment: "that is what I am saying worker is not accepting that data" -- the `Worker` can load the data from the database, `SharedPreferences`, other type of file, etc.